# Netmiko OSError: Search pattern never detected in send_command:

Tags: python, netmiko

I am stuck with this error.

Can anyone help to come out from this error.

```
import netmiko 

Device = {"host":"xxxxxxxxxx", "device_type":"cisco_nxos", "username":"admin", "password":"xxxxxxxx"}

connect =netmiko.ConnectHandler(**Device)

connect.enable()

CLI = "show ip int bri"

print(connect.send_command(CLI))

CLI= "show run"

print(connect.send_command(CLI))
```

I get result for the first cmd but I get error for the 2nd cmd as :

```
  "OSError: Search pattern never detected in send_command:"
```

Comment: `from netmiko import ConnectHandler`
`CLI = net_connect.send_command("show ip int brief") `
`print(CLI)`
Please refer to below link 

https://pynet.twb-tech.com/blog/automation/netmiko.html

Answer (score 4):

`send_command` is **pattern-based**. Meaning it searches for the device prompt to detect the end of output. for `BaseConnection` in `netmiko`, the time for each command to complete is 100 seconds but for Cisco devices is only 10 seconds because `fast_cli` default value is set to `True`. `fast_cli` simply multiplies the 100 seconds by 0.1 (100*0.1 = 10) just to make it faster, yet faster is not always the best option.

You need to set `fast_cli` to `False` to disable the timeout.

> Always set `fast_cli` to `False` when dealing with Cisco devices either `cisco_ios`, `cisco_xe`, `cisco_xr`, or `cisco_nxos` in `netmiko v3.4.0`.

Please try the below code:

```py
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

device = {
    "host": "xxxxxxxx",
    "device_type": "cisco_nxos",
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "xxxxxxxx",
    "fast_cli": False,  # Notice the item here
    "secret": "",  # Enable password (If applicable)
}

# Connect to the device
conn = ConnectHandler(**device)

# Check if connected in user mode and enter enable mode
# Make sure you set the "secret": "xxxx" in the device variable
if not conn.check_enable_mode():
    conn.enable()

intf_brief = conn.send_command("show interface brief")
run_cfg = conn.send_command("show running-config")

# Disconnect to clear the vty line
conn.disconnect()

# Do whatever you like with the outputs after the connection
# is terminated
print(intf_brief)
print(run_cfg)
```

**Another option**

You can use the `send_command_timing` method  without setting `fast_cli` to `False` instead of `send_command`. The former method is **delay-based**. It doesn't search for the device prompt to detect the end of output rather it waits for some time.

```py
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

device = {
    "host": "xxxxxxxx",
    "device_type": "cisco_nxos",
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "xxxxxxxx",
    "secret": "",  # Enable password (If applicable)
}

# Connect to the device
conn = ConnectHandler(**device)

# Check if connected in user mode and enter enable mode
# Make sure you have the "secret": "xxxx" is set in device var
if not conn.check_enable_mode():
    conn.enable()

# Notice send_command_timing method here
intf_brief = conn.send_command_timing("show interface brief")
run_cfg = conn.send_command_timing("show running-config")

# Disconnect to clear the vty line
conn.disconnect()

# Do whatever you like with the outputs after the connection
# is terminated
print(intf_brief)
print(run_cfg)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I shall try and update my result - Vadi

Comment: @vadivel Appreciate if you accept the answer if applicable. Thank you!

Comment: I yet to get chance to try this sir; hope this will work. Will update you. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I don't have rep > 49 so I can't comment on Tes3awy's answer but want to say Thank You.  I'm using a cisco_xr and the "fast_cli": False setting solved the issue.  Interestingly, I am running my script from two different hosts.  The error did not occur on the system running netmiko 3.0.0 but did occur on the system running netmiko 3.4.0.

Comment: Glad I could help. If you get the error, try incrementing the `delay_factor` either in the device dictionary or per `send_command`. For device dict add `{"global_delay_factor": 2}`, and for `send_command` add `send_command("show whatever", delay_factor=2)`

Answer (score 0):

Try **'terminal length 0'** command pass before your actual command.

```
conn.send_command('terminal length 0')
```

Comment: Netmiko does some [session preparation](https://github.com/ktbyers/netmiko/blob/a19c9dad4dd9f81b5d4b59aecf682138c0f36e84/netmiko/base_connection.py#L884) that has `disable_paging()` which is implicitly a `terminal length 0` command. No need to send it again!

Answer (score 0):

Sharing what worked for me hoping it helps others!

**Problem:** Setting `fast_cli` to `False`, as per [@Tes3way answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68817768/8056893), does increase the wait time from 10 to 100 seconds. However, I found the `show inventory` command on a Cisco XR took longer than that, about 140 seconds to complete, hence resulting in the same error message.

**Solution:** Adjust the `delay_factor` argument of the `send_command` method to your own needs:

> Its effect is to modify all of the delays embedded in `send_command` (for example, a `delay_factor=2` will double all of the delays; a `delay_factor=4` will quadruple all of the delays).

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

device = {
    "host": "xxxxxxxx",
    "device_type": "cisco_xr",
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "xxxxxxxx",
    "fast_cli": False,
}

conn = ConnectHandler(**device)
output = conn.send_command("show inventory", delay_factor=2)
```

More info [here](https://pynet.twb-tech.com/blog/netmiko-and-what-constitutes-done.html).